# is there a way to stream multiple desktops to one computer?

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-10, video-streaming, macos-sierra

what I'm trying to do is to set-up a stream of multiple screens in one single screen. The desktops won't have a LAN connectivity so anything LAN related might not help, and all I want is the desktop video feed, no remote desktop accessibility. Also, The computer I will be sending all of the desktops will be a mac, if it isn't possible I also have a partition with Windows 7.

Basically, computer1 will receive desktop video feed from other computers through wi-fi, and then computer1 will stream to the net its own desktop showing all of the desktops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for answering. I found the tool I needed after a couple of days of searching. Infiniscene lets me stream any computer I am paired to, which is amazing, and I can do it with multiple screens at a time. Sadly, I couldn't handle all of the streams coming to my computer and then online so it died quickly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are suggesting the use of Wi-Fi, then you **are** using a LAN.

The short answer is **no** (ish).

The reason is that streaming a desktop takes a *lot* of bandwidth. It is hard enough to do with a single stream. Having multiple streams coming in would flood the best of networks let alone a Wi-Fi network.

On the other hand, if you restricted the screen size of the sending computers, you might be able to get it to work reasonably.

To do this, the sending computers need an application that allows remote access to the desktop. Although you don't want control, I'm not aware of a tool that specifically doesn't allow that.

Windows has the built-in RDP capability, not sure about Mac but there are cross-platform tools such as Teamviewer (though this needs the Internet).

You will need to have a very good and capable computer as the receiver and you will need some really good screen real estate. Using Wi-Fi will mean that you will get a very poor refresh-rate at best which will limit how useful it will be.

Comment: Mac actually has a better MS RDP implementation than Windows, ironically. Currently, the new beta is even better - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/03/30/remote-desktop-client-preview-for-mac-supports-multiple-monitors-and-more/

Comment: Thank you for answering. I found the tool I needed after a couple of days of searching. Infiniscene lets me stream any computer I am paired to, which is amazing, and I can do it with multiple screens at a time. Sadly, you're right with the bandwidth, stream died too fast.